# How can I optimize this Parallel Map Monitor's code?

Tags: parallelization

I want to know how many tasks each kernel has accomplished with the monitor.

**My Attemption:**

```
fun=#^2&;input=Range[10^3];

SetSharedVariable[Finished]
Monitor[Finished={};
    ParallelMap[AppendTo[Finished,{fun[#],ToString@$KernelID}]&,input];
    Print@bar;First/@Finished,
    bar=Evaluate[Column@Table[
        Row@{"Kernel-"<>n<>": ",ProgressIndicator[n/Length[input]]," finished tasks: ",n},
        {n,Union[Last/@Finished]}]]/.CountsBy[Finished,Last]
]//Total//AbsoluteTiming

ParallelMap[fun,input]//Total//AbsoluteTiming

Map[fun,input]//Total//AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

The code is hundred times slower than without monitor.

How can I optimize the monitor?

In other tasks like `fun = PrimeQ[2^# - 1] &; input = Range[30000, 30100];`, these code works better.

Comment: Don't use `AppendTo`. It has to copy the whole list in every call. Moreover, writing to any shared variable should be avoided as much as possible because that will force the kernels into waiting for others to finish their write operation.

Comment: Oh, and this `Dynamic` bogus will also involve the FrontEnd, and there is hardly any better way than slowing your computations down like communicating with the FrontEnd... ;)

Comment: Replacing `Row@{"Kernel-"<>n<>": ",ProgressIndicator[n/Length[input]]," finished tasks: ",n}` by `Row@{"Kernel-", n, ": ", ProgressIndicator[n/Length[input]], 
  " finished tasks: ", n}` also had some positive effect.